# Using underscore like dollar sign in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to shorten up things a bit, so I am making function that implements this

```
Element.prototype.methodName =  function(selector) {
   return this.querySelector(selector);
}
```

It's okay when I tried to use `$` or other letters or words, but it seems like underscore is not working with it, knowing that underscores `_` are valid variable names.

```
Element.prototype._ =  function(selector) {
   return this.querySelector(selector);
}
```

called this way : `_('body')`

**Error Message** : `ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: How does it not work? Do you receive a specific error when you try to invoke `_()`?

Comment: `ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: How are you calling the `_` method?  Just doing `_()` won't work, as `window` is not an `Element`.

Comment: It seems to work on Chromium : http://jsfiddle.net/KrQbN/

Comment: Why not writing your script in readable way, then minimize it with any third party tool ?

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito Then look at the fiddle I made. Doesn't it work for you ?

Comment: I see your edit. I don't see why you think `_('body')` should work. `window` doesn't inherit from `Element`.

Comment: yeah, i figured that out now.. am too naive not to check the code before posting.. umft

Comment: Maybe you want `_ = Element.prototype._ =  function(selector)...`.

Comment: You can't call it like `_('body')`.  That won't work.  You are adding `_` as a method of `Element` objects.  `window` is not an `Element`.  Try doing `window._ = function(selector){` instead.  `Element.prototype._` means that you need to call it on an element: `document.getElementById('test')._('p')`.

Comment: yeah, got the wrong idea.

Comment: I got myself confused because of `$` which i think natively works on google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following HTML:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

And the following JavaScript code:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

Element.prototype._ = function() {
    this.innerHTML = "Bar";
}

foo._();
```

Everthing works fine as expected, at least in Google Chrome. I did not test any other browser. This way you can extend all elements with you desired function. Of course you need to fetch an element first, a call to _(); still gives a reference error. If you you just want a function named _ you would write:

```
function _() {
    // do something
}
```